# Pagination with Polymer Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm got a list with date. This list is load dynamically 20 by 20, so I want to paginate my data.

```dart
@CustomTag('x-friends')
class XFriends extends PolymerElement {
  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;

  // Grown dynamically  
  @published List<UserScore> friends;
  @observable List<UserScore> friendsView;

  int _page = 1;

  XFriends.created() : super.created();
}
```

```dart
 <table>
   <tr template repeat="{{friend in friendsView}}">
     <td>@{{friend.name}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

```dart
 <x-friends friends={{myFriends}}></x-friends>
```

I work when I want to display all friends.
Now, I would like `friendsView` to be a subRange of `friends` by 20 by 20.
I think thought to use `changes.listen` but I does not work because when `friends` is injected in html, the instance change. 
Another problem is I want to display datas even when the loading is not finish. So I have to be prudent with range of list and `friendsView` needs to be dynamical range of `friends`, every time data change in `friends`, data have to change in `friendsView`.

How could I solve this ?
Or maybe somebody has better idea to paginate my list ?

Comment: I think it will work if you just add the friends to the friendsView list that you want to be displayed. How do you set friendsView? Your question doesn't show it.

Comment: Yes, it's another point in my problems : how to set the list. I finally found something interesting

Answer (score 0):

I finally set the friendsView list to observe the friends list.

```dart
final _friendsSymbol = new Symbol("friends");
@CustomTag('x-friends')
class XFriends extends PolymerElement {

  final FRIENDS_BY_PAGE = 20;

  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;

  @published List<UserScore> friends;
  @observable List<UserScore> friendsView = toObservable([]);

  int _page = 0;

  XFriends.created() : super.created(){
    changes.listen((events){
      events.forEach((event){
        if(event is PropertyChangeRecord && (event as PropertyChangeRecord).name ==     _friendsSymbol){
          (friends as ObservableList).changes.listen((_) => _updateViewIndex());
        }
      });
    });  
  }

  bool next(Event e, var detail, Element target) {
    _page++;
    if(_page*FRIENDS_BY_PAGE>=friends.length){
      return dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("nextfriends"));
    } else {
      _updateViewIndex();
      return true;
    }
  }

  bool prev(Event e, var detail, Element target) {
    if(_page>0){
      _page--;
      _updateViewIndex();
    }
    return true;
  }

  void _updateViewIndex(){
    final startIndex = _page*FRIENDS_BY_PAGE;
    final endIndex = min((_page+1)*FRIENDS_BY_PAGE, friends.length);
    if(startIndex < friends.length){
      friendsView..clear()..addAll(friends.getRange(startIndex, endIndex))..sort();
    }
  }

}
```

Every time `friends`us updated, it notify `friendsView`.
I don't now if it's best way, bit it works.